# Substring from right by character SQL

Tags: sql, character, substring

I have a string(s)-

CO_CS_SV_Integrate_WP_BalancingCostRiskandComplexityinYourDRStrat_Apr-Jun

Or

CO_CS_SV_CommVaultTapSponsorship_WP_GartnerNewsletterSmartIdeaforBigData_Jan-Mar

Or

CO_CS_IA_eMedia_WP_Top5eDiscoveryChallengesSolved_Apr-Jun

I need to get the asset name associated with the campaign which is in the campaign name.
So for example  "Balancing Cost Risk and Complexity in Your DR Strat"
would be the asset associated with the first campaign-

"CO_CS_SV_Integrate_WP_**BalancingCostRiskandComplexityinYourDRStrat**_Apr-Jun"

That is my goal.  I want to get just that from the string ("Balancing Cost Risk and Complexity in Your DR Strat".
But I don't see how to strip out the asset from the campaign name.  It is not consistent on position or anything else???
I think I can go from the right and and find the second "_"
But I don't know the syntax.  I get as far as -

select campaign.name
,Right (campaign.name, charindex('_', REVERSE(campaign.name)))  as Test
from campaign

which gives me -
_Apr-Jun

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Use 2 charindexes to get the last "_", and the one before that, obviously on the REVERSE of the string as you have.   Then use SubString to get the text between the two, and then REVERSE again to put it in correct order.

Comment: Thank you Tab.  I will try.  I may come back and ask for help on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a scalar function that accept the string, like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction
(
@str varchar(300)
)
RETURNS varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN

 declare @reverse varchar(200),@idx1 int,@idx2  int

 set @reverse = reverse(@str)

 set @idx1 =  CHARINDEX('_',@reverse)

 set @idx2 =  CHARINDEX('_',@reverse,@idx1+1)

 return  reverse(substring(@reverse,@idx1+1,@idx2-@idx1-1))

END
```

You can try with the following example:

```
select dbo.myFunction('CO_CS_SV_Integrate_WP_BalancingCostRiskandComplexityinYourDRStrat_Apr-Jun');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I do not have permission to create functions on the server

Comment: If you don't have permission to create function, you can use the following expresion in your query: select reverse(substring(reverse(campaign.name),CHARINDEX('_',reverse(campaign.name))+1,CHARINDEX('_',reverse(campaign.name),CHARINDEX('_',reverse(campaign.name))+1)-CHARINDEX('_',reverse(campaign.name))-1)) as Test from campaign

Comment: Thanks.  I think this it what I am trying to do.  When I run the code however, I get a syntax error- I am trying to work out why, but can't figure it out.  "substring requires 3 arguments"   It looks like substring is passed 3 arguments??

Comment: try this: `select reverse(substring(reverse(campaign.name), CHARINDEX('_', reverse(campaign.name)) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', reverse(campaign.name), CHARINDEX('_', reverse(campaign.name)) + 1 ) - CHARINDEX('_', reverse(campaign.name)) - 1)) as Test from campaign`

Comment: I can now create function in the DB.  Your first solution works perfectly, but I want to be able to extract from all the strings in the field 'Campaign.name'.  Do I need to create a table function?

Comment: Just use the following statement: select dbo.myFunction(Campaign.name) from Campaign

Comment: Thank you.  That was my first thought. I did try that. I get 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."   If I run it just on a single string it works!!